# A tool to visualize network connections

Tags: dot, visualize

Currently I'm planning on using dot and it's family.

I want to know if there is something more appropriate?

I'll need to show several levels, card and network connection(input and output):

```
----------
|IOIOIOIO|
--|-------
  \\
---|------
|IOIOIOIO|
----------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the automatic layout graphviz offers, you may use [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) to create nice diagrams. There's an [online version](http://ditaa.org/ditaa/) you may take a look at for a quick test.